# Как написать регулярное выражение для извлечения подстроки из строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько разных строк:

```
http://dtarchive/directory/ag/book
http://dtarchive/main/child/directory/en/paper/
http://dtarchive/sidir/sichild/path/si/mag
http://dtarchive/lkdir/lkchild/path/lk/mz/
```

Из строки нужно извлечь последнюю папку, которая для всех строк разная, и может заканчиваться как слешем, так и без него. Как правильно написать одно регулярное выражение для получения этой папки?

Если строка без слеша, то использую `[^/]*$`, как сделать со слешем в конце, понять не могу.

Также для каждой строки нужно обрезать 2 последние директории.

Например, для строки `http://dtarchive/directory/ag/book`
нужно оставить `http://dtarchive/directory/`,
для строки `http://dtarchive/lkdir/lkchild/path/lk/mz/` нужно оставить `http://dtarchive/lkdir/lkchild/path/`

Как для этого правильно прописать регулярное выражение?

Comment: `/[^\/]+\/?$/`. https://regex101.com/r/mrFQoJ/1

Comment: Ваш вариант получает последнюю фразу со слешем, например - paper/, а не paper

Comment: Правильно, ведь его надо удалить. Или что вам надо получить в результате? Хотите без него, используйте блок предварительного просмотра, `/[^\/]+(?=\/?$)/`.

Comment: Поделитесь кодом, если вам нужно готовое решение.